# Why I'm getting a negative R2 score with Random Forest Regressor?

Tags: python, random-forest, r-squared

I'm trying to predict some variables for MOF's (from a scientific paper) using the Random Forest model in Phyton, but the value of R2 is negative (different from the paper, which was positive). I actually don't know if the problem is with my dataset (that involves assigning numerical values to strings), or with my code. The original dataset is literature dataset and my version is "Dados editados 3"

The Dataset link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17r-hxcuuzEFdfsqcAdHe_9iIp1d51IvL/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=111702212107777597741&rtpof=true&sd=true

I tried to review the code multiples times, though I don't know what I'm doing wrong, because the RF model is a very robust one. Also, I'm removing all Nan values of the dataset with a funcition to detect and remove outliers.

The code:

```
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 

from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV 

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

from sklearn import preprocessing from sklearn import metrics


import numpy as np

import seaborn as sns

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import warnings warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

from google.colab import drive

drive.mount('/content/drive', force_remount= True)

df = pd.read_excel(r'/content/drive/My Drive/Projeto ML/Dados ML.xlsx', sheet_name = "Dados editados 3")

print(df.shape)

df = df.drop(columns = ['Enzyme loading',   'Immobilisation yield',  'Activity retention'] )

df.replace('-', np.NaN, inplace = True)

df = df.dropna()

print(df.shape)

#Modified function

def get_outliers(l):
    #if you keep 0.1 and 0.75 then pretty much no outliers will be filtered
    #q1 is 0.25 quantile and q3 is 0.75 quantile
    q1 = l.quantile(0.25)
    q3 = l.quantile(0.75)
    iqr = q3-q1
    fenceLow = q1 - 1.5 * iqr
    fenceHigh = q3 + 1.5 * iqr
    return [~(i>=fenceLow and i<=fenceHigh) for i in l]

outliers = df.apply(get_outliers)

df =df[~outliers.apply(lambda x:any(x), axis=1)]


X = df.iloc[:, :-1]

Y = df.iloc[:,-1]

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size =
0.25, random_state = 42)


print(X)

scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0.1, 0.9))

x_train = scaler.fit_transform(x_train)

x_test= scaler.fit_transform(x_test)

from sklearn.model_selection import KFold from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score from sklearn.metrics import r2_score from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


rf = RandomForestRegressor()

rf.fit(x_train, y_train)

y_pred = rf.predict(x_test)



k_folds = KFold(n_splits = 6)

scores = cross_val_score(rf, x_train, y_train, cv = k_folds, scoring = "r2")



print("CV Score: ", scores) print("Average CV Score: ", scores.mean()) print("Number of CV Scores used in Average: ", len(scores))
```

Any suggestion about the code or the dataset itself?

[image]

Comment: One issue that I immediately see (which may or may not significantly impact the results)  is that you are fitting the scaler on both the train and test data, which is incorrect. You should only fit it on the training data, after which you only do the transformation for the test data.

Comment: @Oxbowerce I think I understood. But concerning the categorical data, do you have some advice on how I should transform it to numerical values? Also, do you think it's right to do train and test split in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I had a go at processing the data and fitting a random forest.

My steps were:

- Drop columns: DOI, Amino group
- Drop rows with no y value
- Convert strings to numbers, and one-hot encode Ligand column
- Put a test set aside (shuffling & stratified sampling was used)
- Impute missing categorical rows, and missing numerical values

These steps were encapsulated in a pipeline that allows for full separation of train-validation data during CV.

I ran KFold CV and got a median $R^2$ of 0.57.

[image]

One of the folds had a negative (close to zero) $R^2$. I ran CV again, but this time recording all of the predictions and plotting them for each of the 6 folds:

[image]

The model seems to learn the training set well, but generalise relatively poorly. The fold with the lowest score (first plot) had relatively few values at the lower end, and was variable at the upper end. Even though it had a low $R^2$, its RMSE of 20 was as good as most other folds. The folds generally had flat-looking test predictions apart from at y=0 - is y=0 a valid value?

I finally ran leave-one-out CV to see how well it predicts individual samples when trained on the rest of the data.

[image]

To me it seems like the model isn't too good at rendering predictions from these features. I think the $R^2$ could be skewed by the y=0 entries. I then deleted the y=0 rows and re-ran the CV, finding that the score dropped to 0.15.

The bad predictions might be a data issue. Values beyond y=0 the model doesn't make good predictions. Also, tuning of the RF didn't yield significant improvement. `sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor` did a bit better. But I think one ought to try a wider range of models before drawing a definitive conclusion as to whether it's a data problem vs. model problem.

Could you point to the paper that reported their attempt?

My analysis code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn import set_config
set_config(transform_output = "pandas")

np.random.seed(0) #reproducible results

df = pd.read_csv('Dados ML.xlsx - Literature dataset.csv', header=1)

#Remove the DOI column
df = df.drop(columns='DOI')

#Drop amino column
amino_col = 'Dominant amino acid group of enzymes'
df = df.drop(columns=amino_col)

#Replace commas with a dot and
# and '-' with NaN to allow numerical conversion
df = df.apply(lambda col: col.str.replace(',', '.').replace('-', np.nan), axis=1)

#Identify categorical vs numeric columns
ligand_col = 'Ligand precursor functional group'
categorical_cols = [ligand_col,]

numeric_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col not in categorical_cols]

#Convert numbers (currently strings) to numeric types
df[numeric_cols] = df[numeric_cols].astype(np.float64)

#Drop unavailable targets
target_col = 'Reusability: Relative activity after 7 reuse cycles (%)'
df = df.drop(index=df.index[ df[target_col].isna() ])
# df = df.loc[df[target_col] != 0] #Drop zeros assuming they're invalid

def quick_hist(df, title=''):
    df_num = df.select_dtypes(np.float64)
    axs = df_num.hist(bins=50, grid=False, figsize=(7, 5))
    for i, name in enumerate(df_num.columns):
        col_num = df.columns.to_list().index(name)
        axs.flatten()[i].set_title(f'[{col_num}] ' + name[:min(16, len(name))], fontsize=9)
    plt.suptitle(title, fontsize=12)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

#Features/target for preprocessing
features = df.drop(columns=target_col)
target = df[target_col]
quick_hist(features, 'features before outlier removal')

outliers_bool = (
    (features.iloc[:, 2] > 10) |
    (features.iloc[:, 3] > 50) |
    (features.iloc[:, 5] > 50) |
    (features.iloc[:, 10] > 200_000) |
    (features.iloc[:, 11] > 100_000)
)

print('Detected', outliers_bool.sum(), 'outliers')
df_inliers = df.drop(index=features.index[ outliers_bool ])
features_inliers = df_inliers.drop(columns=target_col)
target_inliers = df_inliers[target_col]
quick_hist(features_inliers, 'features after outlier removal')

drop_outliers = False
if drop_outliers:
    print('Dropping outliers'.upper())
    use_features = features_inliers
    use_target = target_inliers
else:
    print('NOT dropping outliers')
    use_features = features
    use_target = target

#Split off a test test to be used as a final unbiased measure
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    use_features, use_target, test_size=0.15, stratify=pd.cut(use_target, bins=5),
    shuffle=True, random_state=1000
)

#Use imputation to fill in missing data
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

cat_transformer = SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')
num_transformer = SimpleImputer(strategy='median')
numeric_features = [col for col in numeric_cols if col != target_col]

imputer = ColumnTransformer(
    [
        ('Categorical imputer', cat_transformer, categorical_cols),
        ('Numeric imputer', num_transformer, numeric_features)
    ],
    verbose_feature_names_out=False
)

#Encode categorical column
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

ligand_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=False, drop='if_binary')
cat_encoder = ColumnTransformer(
    [
        ('Ligand encoder', ligand_encoder, [ligand_col]),
    ],
    remainder='passthrough',
    verbose_feature_names_out=False
)

#Compose a preprocessor pipeline
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

preprocessor = make_pipeline(imputer, cat_encoder)

#Try a random forest
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, KFold, LeaveOneOut

#Shuffle the data per fold for kfold
kfold_cv = KFold(n_splits=6, shuffle=True, random_state=0)
loo_cv = LeaveOneOut()

model = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=np.random.RandomState(0))

#Dummy regressor
# from sklearn.dummy import DummyRegressor
# model = DummyRegressor(strategy='median')

#Another model I tried
# from sklearn import ensemble
# model = ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor(learning_rate=0.1/4, random_state=np.random.RandomState(0))

#Compose pipeline with model
pipeline = make_pipeline(preprocessor, model)

scores = cross_val_score(
    estimator=pipeline,
    X=X_train, y=y_train,
    cv=kfold_cv, scoring='r2', n_jobs=-1
)

print('median score:', np.median(scores).round(3))
print('scores:', scores.round(3))

"""
median score: 0.569
scores: [-0.008  0.473  0.613  0.539  0.799  0.599]
"""

#
# Let's inspect each fold
#
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score

#Get complete results
cv_results = cross_validate(
    estimator=pipeline,
    X=X_train, y=y_train,
    cv=kfold_cv, scoring='r2', n_jobs=-1,
    return_estimator=True,
    return_indices=True
)

trn_predictions = []
val_predictions = []

f, axs = plt.subplots(3, 2, figsize=(8, 4), sharex=True, sharey=True)
axs = axs.flatten()

for fold in range(kfold_cv.get_n_splits()):
    fold_estimator = cv_results['estimator'][fold]
    fold_trn_indices = cv_results['indices']['train'][fold]
    fold_val_indices = cv_results['indices']['test'][fold]

    trn_predictions.append(
        fold_estimator.predict(X_train.iloc[fold_trn_indices])
    )
    
    val_predictions.append(
        fold_estimator.predict(X_train.iloc[fold_val_indices])
    )
    
    #Print fold's RMSE and R2
    fold_val_y = y_train.iloc[fold_val_indices]
    
    print(f'Fold {fold}\n val RMSE:',
          mean_squared_error(fold_val_y, val_predictions[fold], squared=False))
    
    print(' val R2:',
          r2_score(fold_val_y, val_predictions[fold]), '\n')
    
    #Scatter of train and val predictions for fold
    fold_trn_y = y_train.iloc[fold_trn_indices]
    axs[fold].scatter(fold_trn_y, trn_predictions[fold], marker='.', label='train predictions')
    axs[fold].scatter(fold_val_y, val_predictions[fold], marker='.', label='val predictions')
    axs[fold].axline(xy1=(0, 0), slope=1, color='black', linewidth=1, linestyle='--')

axs[-1].set_xlabel('$y$', fontsize=12)
axs[0].set_ylabel('$\hat{y}$', fontsize=12)
axs[0].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.6, 1.7))
plt.show()

#
#Use leave-one-out CV
#
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate

cv_results = cross_validate(
    estimator=pipeline,
    X=X_train,
    y=y_train,
    cv=loo_cv,
    scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error',
    return_estimator=True,
    return_indices=True,
    n_jobs=-1
)

#Get out-of-sample predictions
predictions = np.empty(y_train.shape)
for fold in range(loo_cv.get_n_splits(X_train)):
    predictions[fold] = cv_results['estimator'][fold].predict(
        X_train.iloc[cv_results['indices']['test'][fold]]
    ).item()

print('LOO scores')
print(' RMSE: ', mean_squared_error(y_train, predictions, squared=False))
print(' R2:', r2_score(y_train, predictions).round(3))

val_indices_flat = np.concatenate(cv_results['indices']['test'])

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(y_train.iloc[val_indices_flat], predictions, alpha=0.6)
plt.axline(xy1=(0, 0), slope=1, color='black', linestyle=':')
plt.xlim(-1, 101)
plt.ylim(-1, 101)
plt.xlabel('$y$', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('$\hat{y}$', fontsize=12)
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(5, 3)

"""
#
# Final evaluation on the test set
#
fitted_pipeline = pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
test_predictions = pipeline.predict(X_test)
test_r2 = r2_score(y_test, test_predictions)
test_rmse = mean_squared_error(y_test, test_predictions, squared=False)

print('Final test set scores')
print('RMSE', round(test_rmse, 2))
print('R2:', round(test_r2, 3))
"""
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was trying to reproduce the results of the following paper: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acs.chemmater.1c02476. The dataset is from the support information, and the R2 is suposed to be 0.91 (suport information, RF, LME model). They used boxplot to remove all the outliers and dropped rows with missing data.

Comment: Also, the some of the other ouput values still have an negative R2 value (Activity retention).

Comment: I see. In the code (updated) I dropped 10 outliers based on visual assessment of feature histograms. The KFold score decreased to 0.25, and RMSE increased, so it didn't seem to help. If relevant, you could consider asking the authors what their outlier thresholds/criteria were, or if they're okay with sharing their source code to compare notes.